# transfer data from power bi to excel without changing layout

Tags: excel, dataframe, powerbi, data-visualization, data-analysis

I would like to transform matrix data from power bi to excel without changing formate or layout .is there any way that I cant transform power to excel without changing layout....?
I am looking forward to your answers

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly export Power BI to Excel.
The closet you can do is to use the [Analyse in Excel Plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel) to connect to the data model and recreate the visuals in Excel with the normal limitations of Excel visuals and slicers. You other option is to recreate the Power BI Power Query and Power Pivot models in Excel, rather than do one part of it in Power BI, then the other in Excel.

Comment: I use the pivot and Analyse in excel but when you use this it shows pivot table and when you select field in a PivotTable that changes the layout in the matrix that I created in power bi

Comment: Cube Functions in Excel may help you create a static matrix visual with a defined layout